# Read XML Distinct Nodes Using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML in a string.  I sent a request to a web service and they returned to me an XmlNode.  I now have xmlNode.InnerXml which is the following XML below:

```
<Response>
    <Vehicle>
        ...
    </Vehicle>
    <Premiums>
        <Premium>
          <ID>78601</ID>
          <Name>Premium I</Name>
          <Desc>Description I</Desc>
          <Surcharges>
            <Surcharge>
              <SurchargeID>20</SurchargeID>
              <SurchargeAmount>50.00</SurchargeAmount>
              <SurchargeSelected>TRUE</SurchargeSelected>
            </Surcharge>
          </Surcharges>
        </Premium>
        <Premium>
          <ID>78598</ID>
          <Name>Premium II</Name>
          <Desc>Description II</Desc>
          <Surcharges>
            <Surcharge>
              <SurchargeID>15</SurchargeID>
              <SurchargeAmount>25.00</SurchargeAmount>
              <SurchargeSelected>FALSE</SurchargeSelected>
            </Surcharge>
            <Surcharge>
              <SurchargeID>20</SurchargeID>
              <SurchargeAmount>50.00</SurchargeAmount>
              <SurchargeSelected>TRUE</SurchargeSelected>
            </Surcharge>
          </Surcharges>
        </Premium>
    </Premiums>
</Response>
```

I need the *DISTINCT* Surcharges in the XML.

**For example:**

- Surcharge ID: 20, Amount: $50.00, Selected: True
- Surcharge ID: 15, Amount: $25.00, Selected: False

**Assumptions**:

We are also assuming that any surcharges with the same ID will always have same `SurchargeAmount` and `SurchargeSelected` vlaues.  For example, there will ***never*** be two Surcharges with ID of 20 that have `FALSE` and `TRUE` for `SurchargeSelected`.

**What I have so far:**

```
XmlNode xml = GetPremiumsResponse.GetPremiumsResult;
string xmlString = xml.InnerXml;
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

var _premiumsList = (from r in xDoc.Descendants("Response")
    from p in r.Elements("Premiums")
    select p).ToList();
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me out!!  :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var surcharges = xDoc.Descendants("Surcharge")
                    .GroupBy(s => s.Element("SurchargeID").Value)
                    .Select(g => g.First())
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little help of XPath:

```
var _premiumsList = (from s in xDoc.XPathSelectElements("/Response/Premiums/Premium/Surcharges/Surcharge")
                     select new
                     {
                         ID = (int)s.Element("SurchargeID"),
                         Amount = (decimal)s.Element("SurchargeAmount"),
                         Selected = (bool)s.Element("SurchargeSelected")
                     }).Distinct().ToList();
```

requires `using System.Xml.XPath` at the top of the file.

It uses the fact, that anonymous types have `Equals` and `GetHashCode` defined by default:

> Because the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods on anonymous types are defined in terms of the `Equals` and `GetHashcode` methods of the properties, two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if all their properties are equal.
>
> *from [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination.  However, I am getting an error: `'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' does not contain a definition for 'XPathSelectElements' and no extension method 'XPathSelectElements' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Add `using System.Xml.XPath` at the top of the file.

Comment: One last thing -- I am getting an error when I load my XML into `XDocument.Parse(xmlString)`.  The error is `There are multiple root elements` -- Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, your string does not contain proper XML document. XML specification requires document to have only one root element.

Comment: I should have done `xml.OuterXml` instead and that was the issue.

Comment: One more thing -- Along with the `ID`, `Amount` and `Selected`, how would I add the `Premium/Name` of the Surcharge?  I tried `Name = (string)s.Parent.Parent.Element("Name")` but that didn't seem to work. I got an `Input string was not in a correct format.` error.  Would this be the correct way of going about doing this?